# A Geometric Probability Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This might be a trival problem but I still need to ask these:

1. If there are 100 points in the interval $\left[0,1\right]$, each of their coordinates, $x_i$,
   follows from an uniform distribution, i.e., $X_i \sim U\left(0,1\right)$. Now I just randomly throw a bar with length 0.5 on to this $\left[0,1\right]$ interval (randomly select a continuous subinterval with length 0.5). As a consequence, I would get some points covered. Denote by $N$ the number of covered points. What is the distribution of random variable $N$?
2. Is the above question equivalent to a binomial distribution $N \sim B\left(100,0.5\right)$?
   That is, there is a bar with length 0.5 in the interval $\left[0,1\right]$, and I just randomly throw 100 points on to this $\left[0,1\right]$ interval (It is natural to assume their coordinates follow from $U\left(0,1\right)$). Denote by $N$ the number of points that fall on the bar.
3. What if the number of points in $\left[0,1\right]$ interval is a  Poisson distribution with $\lambda=100$? What is the distribution of random variable $N$ then?

Comment: Seems like each point, independently, has a $50\%$ chance of hitting the bar.  So, yes, equivalent to a binomial distribution.

Comment: This is not that obvious: if the bar is thrown randomly into the interval but always is completely inside the interval, the points near the center of the interval are more likely to be covered by the bar than the others, and that ought to put a bias into the point cloud  (?)

Comment: @R. J. Throw the bar in first then scatter the sand. Each grain has a 50% chance of hitting the bar and none of the grains know where the middle of the interval is.